# Authentication Failed Error - XMPPFramework - not-authorized

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

After successfully connecting to the server, ie. after a successful callback to

`- (void) xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender`

I sometimes get an authentication failure, ie. the following callback is called:

- (void) xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error

The `NSXMLElement` looks like this:

`<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/><text>The response provided by the client doesn't match the one we calculated.</text></failure>`

Like I said, I get this once in a while. I've traced the issue and I've tried several things so far.
Things that's I have looked into and I can confirm so far:

- The username and password are 100% correct
- I'm using the SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication mechanism (`XMPPSCRAMSHA1Authentication`)
- My server supports the PLAIN mechanism as well and it fails with that as well (`XMPPPlainAuthentication`)
- If I try to force a disconnect when I get this error (`[xmppStream disconnect]`) and then in the `xmppStreamDidDisconnect` callback I try to re-open the stream (`[xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error]`) then I get into an infinite loop because the authentication fails consistently

Now, I looked into this even further and when using the SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism it looks like it fails on the second challenge. The client sends something (seemingly valid) to the server but the server doesn't like it and throws the `not-authorized` error.

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: did you find any solution I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your username and Password. If you are passing wrong username and password for authenticate/Login then this **didNotAuthenticate** method will be called